# Get Array Element in Zend View

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-view

i pass an array to my view and i can't show element in my view !
THis is my array : Array ( [pin] => 00000 [card] => 00000 [status] => Y).
thnx for helping me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have array

```
 $arrayData = array ( 'pin' => 00000, 'card' => 00000, 'status' => Y);

$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();

$viewModel->setVariables($arrayData);
```

Now, on view you can directly access as-

```
$pin, $card, etc
```

this will add a single varibale to the view-

```
 $viewModel->setVariable('testVar', 'abc');
```

on view page, just use as

```
 $testVar;
```

Comment: thnx bro i fix it